# php Array N Combinations Works only Up to N=6, I need N=10

Tags: php, arrays

This code, works fine, up to 6 combinations. if I call the function with 10 Combinations, like this: print_r(combinationsOf_FUNQ(10,$array)); It gives a white page, and the Console is also white. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
    for ($z = 1; $z <= 20; $z++) {
   $array[]=$z;
} 

function combinationsOf_FUNQ($n, $array){

        if ($n === 0)
            return array(array());

        if (count($array) === 0)
            return array();

        $x = $array[0];

        $TEMP = array_slice($array,1,count($array)-1);

        $res1 = combinationsOf_FUNQ($n-1,$TEMP);

            for ($i = 0; $i < count($res1); $i++) {
                array_splice($res1[$i], 0, 0, $x);
            }

        $res2 = combinationsOf_FUNQ($n,$TEMP);

        return array_merge($res1, $res2);
    }

echo'<pre>';
print_r(combinationsOf_FUNQ(6,$array));
echo'</pre>';
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) and you can tell us if you get any errors: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as this site name :)
The stack is overflow for many recursions. You really can extend the amount of size, but you again will reach the limit in n=15 for an example.

.... And here you are my solution - without recursive procedure. You have to be noted, that now main indexes of the array aren't sequent, but anyway the subarrays are ordered and can be taken by foreach in right way.
I also used memory extension, because the array appears very big.

```
<?php
 for ($z = 1; $z <= 20; $z++) {
   $array[]=$z;
}
ini_set('memory_limit',-1);

$n=10;
$res=array();
for($k=0;$k<$n;$k++){
    $res[0][$k]=-1;
}

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    foreach($res as $key=>$row){
        if($row[$i]==-1){
            foreach($array as $aa){
                $ft=true;
                for($j=0;$j<$i;$j++){
                    if($row[$j]>=$aa){
                        $ft=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($ft){
                    $tmp=array();
                    for($k=0;$k<$n;$k++){
                        if($k<$i){
                            $tmp[$k]=$row[$k];
                        }
                        elseif($k==$i){
                            $tmp[$k]=$aa;
                        }
                        else {
                            $tmp[$k]=-1;
                        }
                    }
                    $res[]=$tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    foreach($res as $key=>$row){
        if($row[$i]==-1){
            unset($res[$key]);
        }
    }
}


$ii=0;
foreach($res as $row){
    $ii++;
    echo $ii." => ( ";
    foreach ($row as $a){
        echo $a.' ';
    }
    echo ")<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly I changed the limit to 128M and could do up to n=7, but then I had to change it to 256M. Is there a way to improve the code, so that is more efficient?

Comment: Yes I think, if we remove the recursion. Let me try - give me some hours because I just wake up and have to fetch some things before.

Comment: I've looked on it but to resolve without recursion it means to resolve in absolute different way. Can you please explain me the condition of the task. 1. Is it to fin all unique combination of these 20 numbers in n-arrays. 2. And If the order of results is important?

Comment: ... Correction for question one - I mean combination for indexes in n-array, where indexes are from these 20 numbers, but combination like 1,1,1 or 1,1,2 are excluded.

Comment: It appears that it is necessary to avoid use of print_r, because it also uses much mammory but we are on the edge in N=10;

Comment: Thanks again @Kancho lliev, I'll try your code. So far with the memory extension and not printing_r the arrays, it seems to be working. You spotted all the logics. Exactly, combis like 1,1,1 should be excluded. and the order is not important, also is good for testing. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Be my guest :) but the logic as I saw isn't only records like (1,1,1) to be excluded. There is another condition in - all indexes has to be in high order - for example (1,2,4) is acceptable but (1,4,2) is unacceptable. It is clear seen if in your original program replace array z only by 4 elements and n=3. Cheers

Comment: You are right, and that's good too. I tested the execution time of your code against the other one, some times yours was faster, and some other times the other one was faster. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and when I tried 6 it works fine but when I tried 10 it gives me

```
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/index.php on line 43
```

so when I used `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` to exceed the memory.
it works fine but it take some time to finish running